# Which is the latest iPad I can use with latest Xcode for iOS development?

Tags: ios, ipad, compatibility

I am planning to buy an iPad, but not sure whether Xcode will be compatible i.e with an iPad 2. I could not find any Xcode -  iPad compatibility survey.

I guess iPad 1 is too old for any development, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the oldest version that currently supports iOS14 (iPad Air 2) and get something a little newer than that for iOS15 and 16 support in 2021 and 2022

From personal experience don't get a 16GB version as installing the OS is very tricky. Get 32GB minimum.

Via [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/ios-14-compatible-devices-all-the-iphones-that-support-apple-new-operating-system/)

- 12.9-inch iPad Pro
- 11-inch iPad Pro
- 10.5-inch iPad Pro
- 9.7-inch iPad Pro
- iPad (6th gen)
- iPad (5th gen)
- iPad Mini (5th gen)
- iPad Mini 4
- iPad Air (3rd gen)
- iPad Air 2

Comment: I see. But wait, if I downgrade version in deployment info to iOS 9, (it is possible in newest Xcode), then maybe I still can use an iPad 2?

Comment: If you can find an iPad 2 with iOS9 then it might be possible if (no judgment) is where your budget lies. But iOS dev is for better or worse a bleeding edge profession and the Latest GM Release minus 1 rule is fairly sound for learning API.